# How to implement requests sequently in RxAndroid?

Tags: android, rx-android

I need to check if it exits in DB load and pass to view
if not 
load from Server ,Store in DB ,then pass to view
I confused in methods doOnNext(), flatMap() ,I don't which one to use

I couldn't understand the meaning of methods of doOnNext(), flatMap()

Answer (score 2):

I will try to help you with this operators.

As documentation states about doOnNext()

> modifies the source Observable so that it invokes an action when it
>   calls

So check this sample out:

```
public class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Test
    public void testSample() throws Exception {
        Observable.just(1,2,3,4,5)
                .doOnNext(number -> System.out.println("doOnNext: " + number))
                .subscribe(number -> System.out.println("onNext: " + number));
    }
}
```

It will print:

```
doOnNext: 1
onNext: 1
doOnNext: 2
onNext: 2
doOnNext: 3
onNext: 3
doOnNext: 4
onNext: 4
doOnNext: 5
onNext: 5
```

What about flatMaps? Let's check documentation again:

> Returns an Observable that emits items based on applying a function
>   that you supply to each item emitted by the source Observable, where
>   that function returns an Observable, and then merging those resulting
>   Observables and emitting the results of this merger.

So, flatMap creates a new stream based on each item emitted by original stream and them merge those new streams into a single one.

Let's see some code again:

```
public class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Test
    public void testSample() throws Exception {
        Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
                .flatMap(number -> {
                    final String first = number + "A";
                    final String second = number + "B";

                    return Observable.just(first, second);
                })
                .subscribe(flattedItem -> System.out.println("onNext: " + flattedItem));
    }
}
```

It will print:

```
onNext: 1A
onNext: 1B
onNext: 2A
onNext: 2B
onNext: 3A
onNext: 3B
onNext: 4A
onNext: 4B
onNext: 5A
onNext: 5B
```

Hope that it helps you bro!

Best regards.